# Use soon to expire Azure credits

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api, azure-billing

I have a question regarding the free azure credits.

I registered on 11/19/2021 and used around 80$ (60EUR) of services during December and my credits are going to expire on the 12/19/2021.
[image: Credits Balance]

[image: Billing by subscription. Accumulated Costs]

I want to stop my services before the 19, but:

- Will I be billed at the end of the month and, more important, will my credits be used?
- Or they are going to expire on the 19 and at the end of the month, I will be billed on my credit card?
- How can I pay now for the services I used directly with my credits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got free credits only for a month so after 19 your **free subscription** will get deactivate and if you want to continue then your **free subscription** will changed to **Pay-as-you-Go** but it will completely depends on you.

Comment: So if I don't upgrade my free subscription to pay-as-you-go the 80$ I used will be subtracted from the free credits?

Comment: yes Absolutely. It will and your all the free credit will expire on 19 because Microsoft provide those credit only for a month.